# Using fiddler with Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fiddler

I'm trying to hook up fiddler to a java unit test in Eclipse so I can see the soap request when our web service is being called...It works automatically in our .NET harness but is there some setting that needs to be applied for Java? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to configure Fiddler as the HTTP proxy to be used. How? Well I do not know that, for you haven't specified what client you are using, and how your tests are invoking the client.

Comment: We connect to a locally hosted Web Service

Comment: err...sorry to sound dumb, but why would knowing that you're using locally hosted Web Service be of importance here? I would assume that the client has to be configured to use the proxy, irrespective of whether the service is locally deployed or not. [Fiddler can intercept traffic to localhost/127.0.0.1 unless the client does something smart](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have not tried this, but ...

Fiddler establishes itself as a proxy server, listening on localhost:8888

You can configure Java to use a proxy server with the `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

So, if you go into Eclipse and set the "VM" arguments to the following, it should route all traffic through Fiddler (which, of course, must be already running):

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
```

This assumes that your application is using `URLConnection`. If it's using Apache HttpClient or some other library, you may need to check the documentation for that library.

Comment: the proxy configuration for JVM is the right approach, besides, the certificate of fiddler needs to be installed for HTTPS connections.

Comment: In case it doesn't work, I had to use the variables in this way or it didn't work!
-DproxyHost=localhost -DproxyPort=8888

Answer (score 0):

I am usring **Apache HttpClient(4.5.5),  SWT 4, Fiddler 4**, and the VM arguments method does not work for me. So I set the proxy settings in the code and it works.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 8888, "http");
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                .build();
```