# Capturing http with Fiddler using Jsoup (through Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup, fiddler

I'm trying to capture http data with Fiddler through Eclipse, using the `Jsoup` library for http requests.

I'm creating a new question because the others ones are addressing changes to `HttpConnection` etc., and I don't know how that corrolates with `Jsoup`. Excuse my ignorance.

I've tried adding the following to Eclipse VM run arguments (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7435339/992426):

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried adding the following to my code:

```
Properties sysProperties = System.getProperties();
sysProperties.put("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
sysProperties.put("http.proxyPort", "8888");
```

Fiddler seems to be working fine with all my other applications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add those arguments to `Eclipse VM` or to  `VM Arguments` in `Eclipse`'s `Run Configuration`? Former doesn't make sense as your `Program` is launched on a new `VM` by `Eclipse` when you run it.

The below approach is working fine for me, and fiddler is able to intercept `Jsoup` requests.

```
public class JsoupTest
{
static{
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
}
```

Comment: I added the arguments in the lanch config for the given project: http://i.imgur.com/AK75C7u.png 

The snippet I added just in the main of my project. Shouldn't matter where I add it?

Comment: Also, should it matter which version of JSoup I'm using? The only one compatible with my project (for reason's I'm trying to figure out with fiddler), is 1.6.1. As far as I know that shouldn't really matter though.

Comment: @habitats Your `Eclipse` configuration looks Ok. The version doesn't matter here. I suggest you to run a simple `main` program with a `Jsoup` request and confirm the problem. With that being said I can think of only one problem, You might be requesting something on `localhost` from `Jsoup` and configured not to proxy localhost requests on `fiddler`. If that is not the case, then I can't help you anymore with the given information